# How to save Excel xlsx after iOS drag and drop

Tags: ios, swift, excel, drag-and-drop, openxml

I'm trying to use drag and drop to read an xlsx spreadsheet in my iOS app, thanks to some help I've got to the stage where I can get the data and have written this `NSItemProviderReading` class to access it:

```
class ExcelDocument:NSObject, NSItemProviderReading {
let data:Data?

required init(excelData:Data, typeIdentifier:String) {
    data = excelData
}

static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
    return ["org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"]
}

static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
    return self.init(excelData: data, typeIdentifier: typeIdentifier)
}

func write(toFile: String) -> URL?{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(toFile)
            try self.data?.write(to: fileURL)
            return fileURL
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

All this runs fine, and I can open and read the file written by the `self.data?.write` line, but the structure of the xlsx file seems to have been lost - there is no [Content_Types].xml or .rels, so utilities that try and read the file (I'm using [XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter)) throw an error.

Given that Office Open XML is zipped XML I would have thought that the byte stream would work and unzipping would recreate the structure, but it seems not...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it....

The problem was that I was retrieving the drop item with the NSItemProvider I created above..

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    session.loadObjects(ofClass: ExcelDocument.self) { excelItems in
        if let workbooks = excelItems as? [ExcelDocument], let book = workbooks.first, let excelData = book.data {
```

what I should have been doing (and what works) is:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    session.items[0].itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet") { url, error in
        if url != nil {
            (read the excel data from the URL)
        }
    }
```

I stumbled across session.loadFileRepresentation as a new function in iOS 11 in the Apple documentation - I've not seen it mentioned in any of the examples for drag and drop in iOS 11. Anyway, it's all working now